# How to redirect www.foo.com/bar to www.foo.com:8080 without changing url?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

How to redirect www.foo.com/bar to www.foo.com:8080 without "really" changing the url in the url bar?

So I want www.foo.com/bar (+ possible GET parameters / subfolders) to be shown always in the url bar.

Can this be done with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail exactly why you want the address bar to not show the real URL? Basically, you're bypassing one of the most visible security features of a browser. I'm not sure that's a good idea, I suspect many people here think along the same lines, and I'm sure many more would be inclined to help if convinced you're not trying to do something evil.

Comment: Nothing evil can be done here - it doesn't matter to users security-wise what port things are being served off, but they might freak out if they see :8080 because they don't know what it means.

Comment: Of course it matters. *I* would definitely freak out if I thought I was talking to doj.gov on the privileged port 80 but later found out I had been talking to unprivileged port 8080. Perhaps I should rephrase: wrap-per, do you want *client-side* "hiding" (evil), or a server-side solution (ok)?

Answer (score 5):

You need a proxy ([mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)) to do this. Here is an example with [mod_rewrite’s `RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Comment: This will work but if the goal is to keep the client from connecting on port 80 it does no good.

Comment: True but I'm not sure what good this would do. Port 80 would still be blocked and this wouldn't circumvent any firewalls since the client packets would still be going out on port 80.

Comment: I think he just wants to map the port 80 internally to port 8080.

Comment: perhaps. guess we'll just have to see what he says.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted but it does not seem to work completely. My images are missing from the web page. I use relative paths to those so does this proxy somehow mess up the relative pahts? How can I fix it?

Comment: No, the requested paths are passed along just as they come in. Are those files on the hidden server as well?

Comment: They are working if I go straight to www.foo.com:8080 but not throught the proxy (if I go to www.foo.com/bar or any subpage).

Comment: Here is my rewrite:
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^bar(.*?)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/$1 [P]

Comment: And your image URL paths do match this pattern?

Comment: They are in relative path so I guess the relative path somehow gets messed up. I do not know why

Comment: Have you checked what URLs your browser requests? Either inside your browser or in the server access log?

Comment: [29/Apr/2009:09:11:03 +0300] "GET /images/logo/confluence_16.png HTTP/1.1" 404 227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fi; rv:1.9.0.9) Gecko/2009040821 Firefox/3.0.9"

Comment: Well there it is: `^bar(.*?)$` doesn’t match `images/logo/confluence_16.png`. You have to adjust your pattern. Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

No it cant. The :8080 tells the browser what port to connect to the server on. If it's not present it assumes the default for whatever protocol prefix you have (http = 80, https = 443, ftp = 21 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for doing this is probably like my case. Home web server and the router blocks port 80 as its the fefault settings page for the router, so in order to run Xampp in my case i am using port 8080